# Cloud Build Failed to Deploy in GKE

Tags: deployment, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build

I upgraded my cluster to 1.26.2-gke.1000 , after that, all automated deploy failed in the last step with the following error.

`Application in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a Application: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.selector.matchLabels.app.kubernetes.io/name"`

I tried too many solutions without any luck; I deleted everything, re-deployed the deployment, and created a  new cloud build trigger, but I also got the same error!

My deploy.yaml is so simple, and I have more than five deployments all of them were working without any error, but i am getting the same error last couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by deleting this line from the Cloud build Configuration
`--create-application-cr`

I get this solution from this [link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Google-Kubernetes-Engine-GKE/Cloud-Build-failed-with-GKE/m-p/598587/highlight/true)